# keep memory usage low Ubuntu 16.04 Server guest VM

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, memory-usage

I have an Host Machine running KVM+QEMU and multiple guests.
All Guests are running Ubuntu 16.04 (virtual machine installation).

My current problem is, that the host memory consumption (via htop) is at over 90%.
GuestVM1 has 1 GB Memory available. When loggen in, i can see that it only uses about 50 MB. I run `sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3` every hour to keep caches low.

However, when i login to the host and check how much memory GuestVM1 is using on the host, htop returns `VIRT 1480 MB   RES 809 MB   SHR 1020 MB`.

Is there a way to tell KVM, to use less memory (on the host) if the guest is not using all memory and dynamically assing the memory when needed ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to drop caches; Linux will cache data as much as it is allowed to, when memory pressure gets too high it will start to discard pages that are no longer useful and write back dirty pages to free up spare memory.  The Linux philosophy is to keep data cached just in case it needs to be accessed again later, and if memory is required it will discard this data for the memory your processes require

Comment: I've read about this, and it's a nice idea if the operating system is running as host. however i have a lot guest vm's who idle a lot.
And i don't want these idleing vm's to take all the memory, other maybe active vm's are needing.
And as far as i know there is no way an ideling vm knows "hey the other vm's do need memory, lets drop the cache", because the vm's are seperated.